# Post to controller and get result event checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I will try to get result like this :

```
function GetPrice() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPrice")';
        $.post(url, { additionalsId: $("input[name=selectedAdditionals]").val }),
        function(data) {
            $("#TotalAmount").val(data);
        }; //View
    }

public ActionResult GetAdditionalPrice(string[] additionalsId)
    {
        decimal price = 0;
        foreach (var id in additionalsId)
        {
            var aid = int.Parse(id);
            price += db.ContractAdditionals.Where(ca => ca.ContractAdditionalID == aid).Select(ca => ca.Price).Single();
        }

        return Json(price, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }//Controller
```

Why `string[] additionalsId` parameters always undefined? How to post parameter to controller and set result to `#TotalAmount`?

Comment: you forgot to include the closing `()` in your `.val()`

Comment: Moreover, I guess this is just a `string` and not a `string[]`...

Comment: omg i forgot it! thanks :D but i still can't get return Json set to #TotalAmount

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `()` off your `.val` declaration. That should be throwing a JS error in the Console.

To pass back an array, you also need to build one with your selected values

Try this:

```
function GetPrice() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPrice")';
    var items = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name=selectedAdditionals]:checked"), function () {
        items.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.post(url, { additionalsId: items }),
    function(data) {
        $("#TotalAmount").val(data);
    }; //View
}
```

Comment: ok thanks i forgot it, but if i checked more than 1, parameters still only 1 string[] and can't get return Json set to #TotalAmount @mattytommo

Comment: @yovierayz Check my update, you need to build an array for that.

Comment: correct ("input[name=selectedAdditionals]:checked") parameter in controller is null? @mattytommo

Comment: I mean earlier, i have try code like that but parameters still null? @mattytommo

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function GetPrice() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPrice")';
    $.post(url, { additionalsId: $("input[name=selectedAdditionals]").val() }),
    function(data) {
        $("#TotalAmount").val(data.result);
    }; //View
}

public ActionResult GetAdditionalPrice(string[] additionalsId)
{
    decimal price = 0;
    foreach (var id in additionalsId)
    {
        var aid = int.Parse(id);
        price += db.ContractAdditionals.Where(ca => ca.ContractAdditionalID == aid).Select(ca => ca.Price).Single();
    }

    return Json(new {result=price}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}//Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Its solved

```
function GetPrice() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdditionalPrice")';
        var items = new Array();
        $("input[name=selectedAdditionals]:checked").each(function () {
            items.push($(this).val());
        });
        var postData = { additionalsId: items };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#TotalAmount").val(data.result);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
    }
```

Thanks for help :)